# Why won't the terminal display new lines?

Tags: command-line, tty

For example, when I type following command,

```
echo line | (cat >/dev/null; vi)
```

even wrapped in another shell,

```
sh -c 'echo line | (cat >/dev/null; vi)'
```

and returned from Vim, now it won't display carriage return any more.

How can I do to make it again display the new lines? (Without exit.)

Comment: obligatory switch-to-emacs remark :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

try one or both of these:

- type `ctrl+c`, then type `reset`, then press `enter`.
- type `ctrl+c`, then type `stty sane`, then press `enter`.

the `ctrl+c` is to clear any other characters you might have typed in the command line.

`reset` or `stty sane` usually fixes a messed up terminal. Read the man page of `reset` and `stty` for more information.

Note that if the terminal is messed up enough then it might be that not even `ctrl+c` or `enter` will work as expected. There are still other methods to input characters, but they involve ancient dark magic. In that case, it is usually easier to just close the terminal and start another one.

My understanding of the inner workings of a terminal is not deep enough to explain why or how it does that.

Comment: I ended up needing to run `tput smam`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558771/27685

Answer (score 10):

It is not the intended use for `vi` to take input from stdin.

Anyway, you can get newlines again with

```
stty sane
```

without resetting the terminal.